# Mysql 4.0.30 Error 1046... but working on 5.5!

Tags: mysql

On our dev-server we've got MySql version 5.5, but on production server (from aruba.it) we've Mysql 4.0.30.
The SQL query that cause problem is:

> SELECT r.iduser,ra.desapp,
>   r.cognom,f.desfig, r.fl_dip, (Select
>   sum(o.numore)/8 From  OreConsuntive o,
>   Prjtask pt, Prjprogetti pp, Prjordini
>   po Where o.IDuser = '54'and   o.dt_cns >= '20110101' and
>     o.dt_cns <= '20110131' and o.codcop='F00' and
>   o.codtsk=pt.codtsk and
>   pt.codprj=pp.codprj and
>   pp.codord=po.codord and
>   left(po.cliatt,3)<>'CSA' group by
>   o.numore) as TOTGIORNIFATTMESE FROM
>   Risorse r, Figure f, RisorsaArea ra
>   WHERE r.codfig=f.codfig AND
>   r.areapp=ra.codapp AND r.IDuser='54'
>   ORDER BY r.areapp desc

I'll try to execute only this part

> Select sum(o.numore)/8
>   From  OreConsuntive o, Prjtask pt,
>   Prjprogetti pp, Prjordini po Where
>   o.IDuser = '54'and o.dt_cns >=
>   '20110101' and    o.dt_cns <= '20110131'
>   and o.codcop='F00' and
>   o.codtsk=pt.codtsk and
>   pt.codprj=pp.codprj and
>   pp.codord=po.codord and
>   left(po.cliatt,3)<>'CSA' group by
>   o.numore

and it seems to work!
Can the problem be caused by the annidated select ?
How con I modify my query to get a working one on mysql 4.0.30 ?

Thanks a lot!
Davide

Answer (score 0):

MySQL versions prior to 4.1 do not support subqueries. You will have to rewrite your query to avoid that.

Unfortunately, I can't easily tell how to do that in your case, but try reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/rewriting-subqueries.html - it may help you to rewrite it.

I don't know your particular host, but if they cannot upgrade you to a newer MySQL, you should try to downgrade your development server to run the same version as your production server - a lot of things have changed since 4.0, and catching them early might be a good idea.